# Why doesn't the formula work when checking two ECDSA signatures?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, signature, algorithm-design, dsa

There are two generated ECDSA signatures

X - Private key

```
S  = ((Z  + (X * R)) / K) mod n

S` = ((Z` + (X * R`)) / K`) mod n
```

G - Base point, of order n;

```
R  = K  * G
R` = K` * G
```

Why is this formula not working?

```
C = K - K`

R = R` + (C * G)
```

Where exactly do I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think these formulas are correct. So what? In what way are they “not working”?

Answer (score 2):

In ECDSA, the `R` value in the signature is not the elliptic curve point $kG$, but instead only its x-coordinate, that is, an integer.

So, what do you mean by `R' + (C*G)`?  In particular, what do you mean by the operator `+`?

If you mean "the + is an integer modular addition, that is, we take the x-coordinate of the point $CG$, and then add it (modulo $n$) to $R'$", well, that'll give you an integer that's unrelated to $R$ (as $R$ and $R'$ are related as elliptic curve points not integers, and integer addition and elliptic curve operations have little to do with each other)

If you mean "the + is an elliptic curve addition, that is, we find one of the points with x-coordinate $R'$, and add it (using the elliptic curve addition operation) to the point $C\cdot G$), well, that'll work half the time; there are (usually) two elliptic curve points with x-coordinate $R'$, and it'll work if the one you pick just happens to be the original $R'$ point.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong? For example, I want to take two ECDSA signatures: example

Comment: "I want to take two ECDSA signatures" and do what with them?

Comment: @IziTors: I believe you're being mislead by whatever software you are using; when it prints out a point (e.g. C*G), it lists it as a large integer.  Actually, a point consists of both the X coordinate and a Y coordinate (as it is a solution to a specific cubic equation), and there's no obvious way to express both X and Y as a single integer.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you understand how ECDSA or ECC work in terms of operations? The `*` and `+` operations are not actually multiplication and addition (in the last 2 equations). They are the ECC trapdoor function. You can see an animation of such a function here (it should be a gif):

[image]

The `*` and `+` operations just mean applying the trapdoor function x times.

In your example:

```
 R  = K  * G
```

Take the point G and apply the trapdoor function to it K times.

In ECC and ECDSA, a `-` operation (when refering to reversing the trapdoor function) is not possible in most scenarios, since that would mean reversing the trapdoor function, solving the [Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Porblem](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/public-key-cryptography-theory/9788131708323/9788131708323_ch04lev1sec5.html), making the cryptosystem obsolete (in most cases its not possible, but some attacks on weak curves exist).

You can find a bunch of python libraries to do these function multiplications like [ECPy](https://pypi.org/project/ECPy/)

Comment: You *can* use a $-$, both on scalars and EC points. It is the discrete logarithm (the "division" of two points) that is intractable: "find $x$ given $X$,$G$ such that $X=x\cdot G$".

Comment: Yes, I meants doing a ‘-‘ operation on a point to reverse the trapdoor function and solve the ECDLP.

Comment: Read my example and after you understand how a "+" or "*" work in ECDSA, read the wikipedia page for ECDSA. That is why I posted it, trying to explain these operations.

Comment: Here, for example, in my example, I minus:
K = 247441A043B4DFD16A39D3834C596B351D1C3337BB48DC8D1113E9CAB2DE53A0
K` = F9A0A1E22636D8662957B3D62066F182CD1FA37D3457E423CFC8EDB58793DED0
 
C = K - K`
  I receive:
C = D52C6041E281F894BF1DE052D40D864DB0037045790F0796BEB503EAD4B58B30

Then I get (C * G) = DDAAE15676A86275A5D793E5435329C5C3DFE8782E8CB825ED0D0E46E7AA1533

Right?

Comment: @Tudor: I suggest that you fix _"In ECC and ECDSA, a `-` operation is not possible..."_ which is untenable. What you appear to mean is that we can't divide by a point, e.g. compute `R / G` yielding `K`. Note that we _can_ divide by a scalar, e.g. compute `R / K` yielding `G` (we can do this by computing the inverse of `K` modulo the order). Thus we can't say there is no `/`.

Comment: @fgrieu I meant reversing the actual trapdoor function used in ECC. I will update my answer to be more clear. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no "trapdoor function" in standard ECC. "trapdoor function" and "one-way function" are not synonyms.

Comment: @Tudor: you state the `+` operation (point addition on the elliptic curve, illustrated for a curve on $\Bbb R^2$ in your animated GIF) is a trapdoor function, or otherwise irreversible. That's not the case! When we have `A + B = C` with `+` that point addition operation, we can compute `A` from `B` and `C`, with `A = C - B`, and that's nearly as easy as the point addition.